# Batch hide extension for ALL my PDFs on a Mac

Tags: pdf, batch, macos-catalina, hide

I have thousands of PDFs on my Mac (with Catalina) and want to hide the extensions on ALL of them. I've tried the usual recommendation (Finder Preferences, Advanced, uncheck “Show all filename extensions”), but it works only on files that already have their extensions hidden in the Info (Command+I) panel. Even then, the default is to add .pdf to newly downloaded files. Is there a simple alternative that will hide .pdf on all existing files and make this the default for new ones? I don't care about other extensions.